# Add delay between two div in jquery

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, delay

I have two Div (class= sliced) having three images in each(class=tile).
When i am animating with jquery, i am not able to add delay between sliced class. 
However i have added delay between tiles.

index.html

```
<!DOCTYPE html> 
     <html>
        <head>
            <title>Testing Scripts</title>
            <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="style.css">
        </head>
        <body>




        <div id="slider-wrap">
            <div class="sliced">

                    <div class="tile"><img src="http://imageshack.us/a/img545/9813/58zj.jpg" alt"1"></div>
                    <div class="tile tile1"><img src="http://imageshack.us/a/img818/5776/8ik6.jpg" alt"1"></div>
                    <div class="tile tile2"><img src="http://imageshack.us/a/img18/6017/rue6.jpg" alt"1"></div>
            </div>  
            <div class="sliced " >

                    <div class="tile"><img src="http://imageshack.us/a/img163/6131/ld3f.jpg" alt"1"></div>
                    <div class="tile tile1"><img src="http://imageshack.us/a/img838/4102/h0nv.jpg" alt"1"></div>
                    <div class="tile tile2"><img src="http://imageshack.us/a/img833/6500/dp5e.jpg" alt"1"></div>
            </div>  
         </div>   


         </div>
        <script src="jQuery.js"></script>
        <script src="jquery.easing.1.3.js"></script>
        <script src="script.js"></script>
        <script>$('.sliced').slider();</script><!--Calling plugin with   -->
        </body> 
     </html>
```

CSS

```
body {
    width: 960px;
    margin: 100px auto;
    font-family: helvetica;
    font-size: 20px;
 }

#animate {
    width: 100px;
    height: 30px;
    margin-bottom: 10px;
    font-size: 16px;
}
.sliced {
    position: relative;
    margin: 5px 5px;
    width: 900px;
    height: 200px;
    border: 2px solid black;
    }
.box {
    width: 600px;
    border: 2px solid rgba(0,0,0,.05);
    padding: 10px 10px;
}

img {
    width: 270px;
    height: 150px;

}
.tile {
    position: absolute;
    float: left;
    margin: 25px 15px;
}
.tile1 {

    left: 280px;

}
.tile2 {

    left: 560px;

}
```

JScript:-

```
function Slider(ele){
    var $ele = $(ele), //Jquery Object of .sliced class
        $tiles = $ele.find('.tile');  //$tiles contains all .tile class as jquery Object
        $.each($tiles,function(index,value){ 
               setTimeout(function(){
                $(value).fadeOut(1000);
                },1000*index);

        });

} 

$.fn.slider = function(){   
       //This stores all .sliced class as Jquery object                                      
    return this.each(function(){  //Iterarting over each class provided 
        var slider = new Slider(this);  //Slider is constructor function
        //console.log(slider);
    });
}
```

Comment: I'm unsure what you are looking to do.  Is this what you are looking for: [fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/davidcl64/hwgWP/)?

Comment: I want to add delay between fading of 3rd & 4th Image.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Finally after so many hit and trials, i figured it out myself

JS:-

```
function Slider(ele,index){
    var $ele = $(ele), //Jquery Object of .sliced class
        $tiles = $ele.find('.tile'),//$tiles contains all .tile class as jquery Object
        delay = 5000;  //Delay between two divs
        setTimeout(function(){
             $.each($tiles,function(index,value){ 
               setTimeout(function(){
                $(value).fadeOut(1000);
                },1000*index);
          });
        },delay*index);


} 

$.fn.slider = function(){   
       //This stores all .sliced class as Jquery object                                      
    return this.each(function(index){  //Iterarting over each class provided 
        var slider = new Slider(this,index);  //Slider is constructor function
        //console.log(slider);
    });
}
```

Answer (score -1):

Maybe something like this

```
$( "div" ).click(function() {
  $( this ).addClass( "big-blue", 1000, "easeOutBounce" );
});
```

can help?